# How to get a Fraction of a Row in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a Container containing a Row, I am trying to size two containers inside it by fractions.
I tried using `FractionalSizedBox` but the output is really not it.

[image]

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInserts.all(10.0),
   height: 200,
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(color: Colors.redAccent, width: 1.0),
   ),
  child: Row(
      children: [
        Flexible(
          child: FractionallySizedBox(
            heightFactor: 1, widthFactor: 0.5,
            child: Container(color: Colors.orange),
          ),
        ),
        Flexible(
          child: FractionallySizedBox(
            heightFactor: 1, widthFactor: 1.5,
            child: Container(color: Colors.blue)
          )
        ),
        
      ],
    )
)
```

Comment: why don't you use the `Expanded` widget? with its flex value its much easier

Comment: got it, didn't know about that flex property @towhid

Comment: You want the orange container to have the same size as the blue one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run this on DartPad.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Row(children: [
      Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(color: Colors.redAccent, child: Text("%25"))),
      Expanded(
          flex: 3,
          child: Container(color: Colors.greenAccent, child: Text("%75"))),
    ]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of wrapping the container with `FractionallySizedBox` you could just use the `flex` property in the `Flexible` widget to get the job done.

Which will change your above code to this.

```dart
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
  height: 200,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(color: Colors.redAccent, width: 1.0),
  ),
  child: Row(
    children: [
       Flexible(
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(color: Colors.orange),
          ),
       Flexible(
          flex: 2,
          child: Container(color: Colors.blue),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

You can try it out, by running this dartpad : https://dartpad.dev/2bed7e8dffc17c273c87db66e1012927?